# Strange/interesting behaviour with std::vector iterators and resizing/reserving

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have two very similar bits of code; this:

```
std::vector<int> fail{0};
fail.reserve(2);
std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = fail.begin(), it2 = fail.begin() + 1;
fail.push_back(0);
it1 == it2;
```

which throws a "vector iterators incompatible" exception and this:

```
std::vector<int> fail{0, 0};
fail.reserve(3);
std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = fail.begin(), it2 = fail.begin() + 1;
fail.push_back(0);
it1 == it2;
```

which doesn't. It seems to be due to the `it2` being the end of the vector in the first example but not in the second, but I'd just like to get a full clarification for why the first throws but the second doesn't.

For reference I am using MSVC.

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector::push_back` always invalidates the past-the-end iterator, so in the first case `it2`. This happens regardless of resizing.

All other iterators stay intact if the vector does not reallocate, that's why they second snippet is fine.